# Croppie is Not Working in Jquery Fancybox popup modal

Tags: jquery, fancybox, croppie

I had used Jquery [Croppie](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/) for requirement of crop or scale image in popup model, I had used fancybox for show image in popup, now i want to make crop image or scale image in popup modal i tried but its not working anymore.
I had done popup modal with,

```
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="{{ asset('public/img/noimage.png') }}" id="fancybox_anchor">
   <div id="profile_pic_div" style="background-image: url('{{ asset('public/img/noimage.png') }}')"></div>
</a>
```

Popup model is perfectly showing the image but now i want to make it crop, scale, resize using croppie 
I had tried like ,

```
$( '.fancybox-image-wrap img' ).croppie({
        enableExif: true,
        viewport: {
            width: 250,
            height: 250,
        },
        type: 'circle',
        boundary: {
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        }
});
```

When Popup opens Image parent class is `fancybox-image-wrap` thats why i take it as a selector. In normal mode its working but how can i do that it in popup model. Please help. I am totally stuck in this.

Thank you.

Comment: Try setting `touch:false, clickContent:false` (for fancybox) to disable default behavior.

Comment: for what to apply this?? am sorry i did not understand what are you saying.

Comment: @Janis i had done nothing jquery code for fancybox  its just an require resources i have added and the simple anchor tag opens fancy box.

Comment: In case you have not noticed, fancybox captures all mousedown, mousemove, etc events to enable swiping/dragging by default. And this is how you can disable that.

Comment: @Janis Can u please detail me more.?

Comment: I had disabled this two, now??

Comment: Then it should work. A bit weirdly, but works - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bvjeLZ?editors=1010

Comment: Awesome Brother Its working as i expected... can u please post your answer with this link provided, I will mark as right answer with upvote...
:)

Comment: a little more help require. After i scale image in popup modal how can i get that scaled image in normal screen after closing fancybox window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more complete example of using callbacks to initialise croppie and to get result:

```
var myCroopie;

$('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({
  touch: false, 
  clickContent: false,
  animationEffect: false,
  afterLoad : function(instance, current) {
    myCroopie = current.$image.croppie({
    });
  },
  beforeClose : function() {
    myCroopie.croppie('result', 'html').then(function(html) {
      // html is div (overflow hidden)
      // with img positioned inside.
      $("#rez").html(html);
    });
  }
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bvjeLZ?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks a lot brother... It realy helps